# Active Admin won't install: superclass mismatch for class StringIO (TypeError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I was recently trying to install Active Admin but it keeps producing this error below. I have added activeadmin, devise, draper, cancancan, and pundit to the gemfile. For reference, I am trying to install Active Admin on a basic blog app for ruby on rails (https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html)

Command:

`rails g active_admin:install`

Error:

```
/home/hjamal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/bootsnap-1.9.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require': superclass mismatch for class StringIO (TypeError)
from /home/hjamal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/bootsnap-1.9.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from /home/hjamal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/bootsnap-1.9.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
    from /home/hjamal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/bootsnap-1.9.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from /home/hjamal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/bootsnap-1.9.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from /home/hjamal/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.8/lib/ruby/2.5.0/psych/nodes/node.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/hjamal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/bootsnap-1.9.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
    from /home/hjamal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/bootsnap-1.9.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from /home/hjamal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/bootsnap-1.9.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
    from /home/hjamal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/bootsnap-1.9.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from /home/hjamal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/bootsnap-1.9.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from /home/hjamal/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.8/lib/ruby/2.5.0/psych/nodes.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/hjamal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/bootsnap-1.9.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
    from /home/hjamal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/bootsnap-1.9.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from /home/hjamal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/bootsnap-1.9.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
    from /home/hjamal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/bootsnap-1.9.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from /home/hjamal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/bootsnap-1.9.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from /home/hjamal/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.8/lib/ruby/2.5.0/psych.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/hjamal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/bootsnap-1.9.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
    from /home/hjamal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/bootsnap-1.9.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from /home/hjamal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/bootsnap-1.9.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
    from /home/hjamal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/bootsnap-1.9.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from /home/hjamal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/bootsnap-1.9.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from /home/hjamal/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.8/lib/ruby/2.5.0/yaml.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/hjamal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/bootsnap-1.9.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
    from /home/hjamal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/bootsnap-1.9.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from /home/hjamal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/bootsnap-1.9.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
    from /home/hjamal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/bootsnap-1.9.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from /home/hjamal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/bootsnap-1.9.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from /home/hjamal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/bootsnap-1.9.1/lib/bootsnap/compile_cache/yaml.rb:55:in `init!'
    from /home/hjamal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/bootsnap-1.9.1/lib/bootsnap/compile_cache/yaml.rb:50:in `install!'
    from /home/hjamal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/bootsnap-1.9.1/lib/bootsnap/compile_cache.rb:20:in `setup'
    from /home/hjamal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/bootsnap-1.9.1/lib/bootsnap.rb:70:in `setup'
    from /home/hjamal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/bootsnap-1.9.1/lib/bootsnap.rb:112:in `default_setup'
    from /home/hjamal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/bootsnap-1.9.1/lib/bootsnap/setup.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/hjamal/blog/config/boot.rb:4:in `require'
    from /home/hjamal/blog/config/boot.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/hjamal/blog/config/application.rb:1:in `require_relative'
    from /home/hjamal/blog/config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/hjamal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/spring-3.0.0/lib/spring/application.rb:92:in `require'
    from /home/hjamal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/spring-3.0.0/lib/spring/application.rb:92:in `preload'
    from /home/hjamal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/spring-3.0.0/lib/spring/application.rb:155:in `serve'
    from /home/hjamal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/spring-3.0.0/lib/spring/application.rb:143:in `block in run'
    from /home/hjamal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/spring-3.0.0/lib/spring/application.rb:137:in `loop'
    from /home/hjamal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/spring-3.0.0/lib/spring/application.rb:137:in `run'
    from /home/hjamal/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.8/gems/spring-3.0.0/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/hjamal/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.8/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85:in `require'
    from /home/hjamal/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.8/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85:in `require'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Comment: first try to remove bootsnap and cancancan from Gemfile, then do a bundle install, then try if you can start a rails console. If this also fails, perhaps post your Gemfile aswell, and provide more configuration data for us to reproduce.

Comment: Any resolution to this? I'm getting this to after updating my gems.

Comment: Looks like I was running an older version of ruby (2.5.8). It worked after I upgraded to ruby-3.0.0.

Comment: I'm stuck using `ruby 2.7.2/3/4` and this StringIO error won't go away for me.